# How do I override the SQL for a CRecordSet and then requery?

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++, odbc, visual-c++-6

I have a CRecordSet (Visual C++ 6.0) and I'm using ODBC to connect to postgresql 8.0.8.

__

The problem: I insert a row into a table with a serial id (autoincrement), and I would like to retrieve the id after my insert.

I can't use the RETURNING keyword, not supported on this version of PGsql, but I can use currval('sequence').

However, in my code, I need to execute the default query and then override it to execute the query with currval().

From what I understand, I can only override the query by calling CRecordSet::Open() again, which would create a new session, rendering currval() useless.

__

So: How can I override the SQL, then execute this new query via a Requery() and not via Open()?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, currval() is not connection specific. You should get the correct value back on the new connection. You could also try and append the 'select currval()' at the end of your INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1); SELECT currval('mysequence');
```

Comment: currval is connection-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use currval().  This is session-specific and concurrency safe.  The syntax is above in Imraan Parker's answer.

The fact though is that with a new session there is no safe way to get this info.